# Sandbox Paypal keeps returning error

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I've created a PayPal Sandbox Buyer and Seller accounts to test my website store but for some reason everytime I login in Sandbox I get this error:

"We are unable to validate your information. Please try again."

With a button to "Return to Merchant".

Already cleared my cookies...

Comment: Make sure your currencies are configured properly. IF you are making payments in USD. Make USD primary in your paypal settings.